# How to free space on hard disk to install another OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Here is the scenario.

I have Windows 7 installed on my Dell Inspiron 15" C: drive. The C: partition size is equal to the capacity of the hard disk, but the used space on C: is far less than that.

I want to install Ubuntu on this laptop, too. Is there a way I can free half of the space occupied by the Windows 7 partition and install Ubuntu on it?

In short, want to install Ubuntu without losing neither the Windows installation nor my previously stored data and programs.

Comment: Tip - always back up first - that way if anything goes wrong you can always restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Ubuntu installation disks have [tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition) to shrink Windows (and other) partitions without losing data.

You could also boot into the Ubuntu Live CD and use GParted (GUI tool) to resize your partitions.

As always, making a backup is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you have divide atleast two drive in your system .in another partition you make some free space to install that ubuntu it will definitely working with out failed OS corruption